# Windows 7 very slow to connect to network

Tags: windows-7, networking

The computer is connected with ethernet using the Realtek RTL8111E on a Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD4-B3 motherboard.  I had to install Realtek LAN Driver 7.049.0927.2011 to make the networking function at all.  It is running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, with all updates installed.

On bootup, there is no networking.  If I wait about a minute, it eventually comes up.

The computer dual boots Ubuntu Precise, which connects to the network with no delay.  The DHCP server is dnsmasq on a SheevaPlug running Debian Squeeze.  I have double checked that my router's DHCP server is disabled.

I have used Windows very little since the XP days, so I have no idea where to look for diagnostic messages or logs.

Comment: Does this happen on other networks?

Comment: This particular computer only connects to one network.  It is a desktop with no wireless capability.

Where does Windows log networking stuff, especially stuff like DHCPDISCOVER/DHCPREQUEST/DCHPOFFER/DHCPACK messages?

Comment: Let me be clear - 95% of machines only connect to one network.  I am suggesting that you test this on another network as a troubleshooting step. :) (In regards to your question, that sort of stuff doesn't show up unless there are significant errors, at which point it should be fairly obvious in Event Viewer.  This sort of thing has not really changed in over a decade.)